# Доступ к ресурсу REST

Tags: backbone.js, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Имеется url ресурса: **http://localhost/users/:user_id/comments**

Модель:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/users",
);
```

Как отправить GET запрос через модель **User** на ресурс comments?

P.S с учетом того что данная модель должна так же посылать запросы на http://localhost/users (что сейчас и делает)

Answer (score 1):

если

```
var user = new User({id: 42});
user.fetch()
```

выполнит запрос на `http://localhost/users/42/`, то вы в праве написать 2 метода:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    urlRoot: "/users",

    commentsUrl: function(){
        return _.result(this.url)+'/comments';
    }

    fetchComments: function(options){
        // ....
        return Backbone.$.ajax(
            _.extend({url: this.commentsUrl()},options)
        );    
    }
);
```

И вообще с Backbone вы в праве делать всё, что захотите(без фанатизма естественно), это даже написано в оффициальной документации [There's More Than One Way To Do It](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-tim-toady)

Comment: Спасибо. Но т.к это полноценный ресурс REST то Ваш код не будет отправлять PUT DELETE POST запросы

Comment: это ещё почему?

    user.fetchComments({type: 'POST'});

Comment: Манипулировать опциями запросов ({type: 'POST'} и т.п) это конечно хорошо, но хотелось бы знать имеется ли более элегантный вариант как с моделью что я написал, то есть 
  
    model.set({name: "demo"})
    model.save // PUT

    model.destroy // DELETE

и т.п

Comment: эти вещи реализованы в Backbone, если хотите, чтобы поверх работы родных save, destroy относительно модели работали ещё и другие вам прийдётся их реализовать самостоятельно, или же выделть отдельную сущность под комменты